# PHP logout function error

Tags: php, logout

I've had a look around and seem to have a unique question here (new to this, so be kind on downvotes)

I have a logout function that I use as part of a registration system I'm putting together. The problem is, it fails when using IE and Safari (still shows users as logged in on the home page after clicking appropriate link). Clearly something is going wrong here, but from reviewing the code multiple times it doesn't seem to have anything wrong in it? My question is why is this not working in IE and Safari? Does it have smoething to do with browser support?

This is the applicable code:

```
**logout.php**

    <?php
    include_once 'functions.php';
    sec_session_start();

    // Unset all session values 
    $_SESSION = array();

    // get session parameters 
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();

    // Delete the actual cookie. 
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, 
        $params["path"], 
        $params["domain"], 
        $params["secure"], 
        $params["httponly"]);

    // Destroy session 
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ../index.php');

Appropriate function in **functions.php**

    function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name 
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session 
    (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], 
    $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
    }
```

I've included comments to make this a bit easier to follow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doing stuff with cookies and redirecting at the same time can sometimes be problematic. I would recommend that remove that redirect, and logout.php with it - and then simply call your index.php with a GET parameter that then makes it perform that logout stuff _in_ the index.php, without redirecting all over the place.

Comment: @CBroe So you suggest including that entire script in index.php? how would that work then? Sorry, relatively new to PHP and I'm following a course for the above, adjusting it and developing it as I go